# Ant to Gradle migration

Tags: java, xml, ant, gradle

I am currently migrating a very large and complex build process from ANT to Gradle.
I have tried a straight import of the ANT build file and consistently got this error

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [AntClassLoader[...project classpath....]] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" was loaded by [org.gradle.internal.classloader.MutableURLClassLoader@b77b093].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate configurator [org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
:single FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':single'.

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-tests.xml:136: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-db.xml:57: Schema text failed: Unable to read XML
```

I tried:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

The Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':single'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-tests.xml:255: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-tests.xml:136: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-db.xml:57: Schema text failed: Unable to read XML
at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:568)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.ant.AntTarget.executeAntTarget(AntTarget.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 53 more
Caused by: /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-tests.xml:136: The following error occurred while executing this line: /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-db.xml:57: Schema text failed: Unable to read XML
at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:568)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
... 75 more
Caused by: /home/XXX/workspace/tester-fb-36-gradle/build-db.xml:57: Schema text failed: Unable to read XML
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask.execute(SchemaExportTask.java:172)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
... 87 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:513)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:509)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addFile(Configuration.java:504)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addFile(Configuration.java:483)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask.getConfiguration(SchemaExportTask.java:225)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask.execute(SchemaExportTask.java:169)
... 99 more

Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:458)
at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
... 105 more
```

BUILD FAILED

I am posting the full stack trace as eventually someone will ask for it.

I thought there may be a conflict between XML parsers being loaded by Gradle and then by ANT, our build for tests imports another xml file which I thought could be conflicting, I subsequently translated the file into Gradle removing the need to import the xml, got the build going with that and upon trying to import and run the build-tests file I get the same error again.

I am unsure as to which end of this is causing the problem, dom4j or log4j, I suppose it could be a classloader clash between Gradle loading its own log4j and the project loading its loggers or some as yet unknown issue with dom4j,

I have updated dom4j to 2.0, though that project is apparently no longer in action, I have tried removing dom4j form the build path but that just causes more problems as its required for multiple classes.

I fold for the moment, hopefully someone has some insight.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. What's your ANT build script and your corresponding Gradle script. What are you trying to do and what is it you want to do very simply? Are you trying to invoke an Ant task through Gradle?

Comment: I am trying to migrate an entire build process from Ant to Gradle, as per the title of my question.  My initial attempts at invoking Ant tasks through gradle resulted in the above (beautifully formatted, thank you for that) error.  The build relies on > 6 Ant files which depending on the task run import each other. I wish to find a resolution to this error so I can continue on with the process of migration.

Comment: Do you import Ant scripts, execute Ant tasks. or both? Which exact operation causes the problem?

Comment: I think the Ant scripts are required alongside the gradle script to help you. I don't think it is a [tag:gradle] issue - it's a [tag:hibernate] issue - in your exception trace - `org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)` and in another forum the same issue & the root cause was hibernate - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=969436

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser It seems to be down to the schema export task in one of our Ant files, I am importing one file into build.gradle which then imports another internally.  This build works as expected when run through Ant, I only get this error when I import the file and run via gradle so I'm not sure that this is a hibernate issue as suggested by FirstZero.

Comment: Sorry, can't say from here how to fix this problem.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser does Gradle use dom4j internally?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where/how.

Comment: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1212 @PeterNiederwieser  Its very old I know but it does seem there have been classloader issues in the past. could it be related to this? Still not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Looks different. If you can provide a minimal self-contained reproducible example over at http://forums.gradle.org, someone might be able to have another look. Alternatively, you could call the Ant build as an external process, or try to do more on the Gradle side, rather than reusing parts of the Ant build.

Comment: Its not really feasible to produce a self contained reproduction of this situation, the project is too big and I would most likely spend far too much time putting it together, time which would be better spent translating the db set up functionality in Gradle as thats is going to have to happen either way. Thank you for your responses, I am now 2/3rds of the way through translating this file, there are more questions to come I promise you that...